# Strange IE JQuery problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Works in chrome, and works in ff, but not in IE.

IE refuses to call the the function in my callback.

I'll post the code I feel is relevant:

```
function slideRight(){
    disableAll();

    var leftMarg = parseFloat(opiHolder.css("marginLeft"));
    var fullWidth = parseFloat(opiHolder.css("width"));

    if(fullWidth + leftMarg > opiWidth) {

        opiHolder.animate({marginLeft: '-=' + (fullWidth + leftMarg - opiWidth) + 'px'}, 'slow', function() {

            alert("this is working now");       

            enableAll();

        });

    } else {
        enableAll();
    }       
}
```

This seems so strange so I ran an experiment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = "1000";
    var b = "800";

    var c = parseFloat(a);
    var d = parseFloat(b);

    $("#suck").animate({marginLeft: '-=' + (c + d) + 'px'}, 'slow', function(){funcX();});              

    function funcX(){
        alert("here");
    }
});
```

THIS works perfectly.

I can see the "here" alert, but not the "this is working now" alert.  It's really bringing me down!

I've replicated the conditions as best I can...

What is happening?

ANY help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

--Mike

edit: here is the code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewer = $("#viewer");
    var lock = false;

    var contactsCounter = 1;
    var companyCounter = 1;

    var conHolder = $(".contactsHolder");
    var viewHolder = $("#viewerHolder");

    var frontStop = conHolder.css("marginLeft");
    var ERROR = 0;

    var viewerHolderPadding = parseFloat($("#viewerHolder").css("padding-top"));
    var superViewerPadding = parseFloat($("#superViewer").css("padding-top"));
    var contactsHolderMargin = parseFloat($(".contactsHolder").css("margin-top"));
    var viewerHeight = parseFloat($(".viewer").css("height"));
    var contactsWidth = parseFloat($(".contacts").css("width"));
    var contactsMarginRight = parseFloat($(".contacts").css("margin-right"));
    var contactsMarginLeft = parseFloat($(".contacts").css("margin-left"));

    var moveHorzAmount = contactsWidth + contactsMarginRight + contactsMarginLeft;
    var moveVertAmount = viewerHeight + contactsHolderMargin;
    var detectViewerMeasure = viewerHolderPadding + superViewerPadding + contactsHolderMargin;

    var companyInput = "Company:<select><option>Wendys</option><option>McDonalds</option><option>Earls</option></select>-or-<input type='text' />";
    var contactInput = "<div class='formholder'><table border='0'><tr><td>Contact Name:</td><td><input type='text' /></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type='text' /></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Position in Company:</td><td><input type='text' /></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Phone number:</td><td><input type='text' /></td><td>Extension:</td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr><tr><td>Prime contact?</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td><td></td></tr></table></div>";

    $("#controls").draggable({ opacity: .7 });

    function detectViewer(){

        var companies = [];
        var pos;

        viewHolder.children().each(function () {
            companies.push($(this));
        });

        for(var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++){

            pos = companies[i].position().top;

            if(pos == detectViewerMeasure){

                var idInPlace = companies[i].attr("id");

                return idInPlace.replace("viewer", "");

            }
        }

        alert("Failure in detectViewer() class, contact administrator");

        return -1;
    }

    function disableAll(){
        $("#right").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#left").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#up").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#down").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#rem").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    function enableAll(){
        $("#right").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#left").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#up").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#down").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#rem").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    $("#left").click(function(){
        disableAll();

        var currentCompany = detectViewer();
        var toSlide = $("#holder" + currentCompany);
        var currentPosition = toSlide.css("marginLeft");

        if(currentPosition != frontStop || currentPosition < frontStop) {

            toSlide.animate({marginLeft:'+=' + moveHorzAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function() {
                enableAll();
            });

        } else {
            enableAll();
        }
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {

        disableAll();

        var currentCompany = detectViewer();
        var toSlide = $("#holder" + currentCompany);
        var left = parseFloat(toSlide.css("marginLeft"));
        var width = parseFloat(toSlide.css("width"));

        if((left + width - moveHorzAmount) > moveHorzAmount){

            toSlide.animate({marginLeft:'-=' + moveHorzAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function(){

                enableAll();

            });

        } else {
            enableAll();
        }
    });

    $("#down").click(function() {
        disableAll();

        var top = parseFloat(viewHolder.css("marginTop"));
        var height = parseFloat(viewHolder.css("height"));

        if((height+top) > moveVertAmount) {

            viewHolder.animate({marginTop: '-=' + moveVertAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function( ){
                enableAll();
            });

        } else {
            enableAll();
        }
    });

    $("#up").click(function() {

        disableAll();
        var top = parseFloat(viewHolder.css("marginTop"));

        if(top < 0) {

            viewHolder.animate({marginTop: '+=' + moveVertAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function(){
                enableAll();
            });

        } else {
            enableAll();
        }
    });     

    $("#add").click(function(){

        var viewerDetected = detectViewer();
        var tmpString = "#viewer" + viewerDetected + " > #contactsHolder";
        var companyAndContact = $(tmpString);
        var currentViewer = $("#holder" + viewerDetected);
        var size = currentViewer.css("width");
        var num = parseFloat(size);
        var px = "px";

        num += moveHorzAmount;  
        currentViewer.css("width", num);
        contactsCounter++;

        var tmpString = "#viewer" + viewerDetected + " >  #holder" + viewerDetected;
        var companyAndContact = $(tmpString);
        companyAndContact.append("<div class='contacts' id='con" + viewerDetected + "_" + contactsCounter + "'>" + contactInput + "</div>");
        currentViewer.animate({marginLeft:'-=' + moveHorzAmount + 'px'}, 'slow');

    });

    $("#addComp").click(function() {
        companyCounter++;
        var viewerDetected = detectViewer();
        viewHolder.append("<div class='viewer' id='viewer" + companyCounter + "'><div class='contactsHolder' id='holder" + companyCounter + "'><div class='contacts' id='con" + viewerDetected + "_" + "1'><div class='formholder'>" + companyInput + "</div></div></div></div>");
        viewHolder.animate({marginTop: '-=' + moveVertAmount + 'px'}, 'slow');

    });

    $("#rem").click(function(){

        disableAll();

        var kids = [];
        var currentCompany = detectViewer();
        var toRem = $("#holder" + currentCompany);

        toRem.children().each(function () {
            kids.push($(this));
        });

        var viewerView = (Math.round(parseFloat(toRem.css("marginLeft"))/moveHorzAmount))*-1;

        if(viewerView !== 0) {
            var currentID = kids[viewerView];
            var animateTo = parseInt($(".contacts").css("marginLeft"));

            toRem.animate({marginLeft:'+=' + moveHorzAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function(){
                enableAll();
            });

            $(currentID).remove();

            var size = $("#holder" + currentCompany).css("width");
            var num = parseFloat(size);
            var px = "px";
            num -= moveHorzAmount;  
            toRem.css("width", num + px);

        } else {

            enableAll();
        }
    }); 

    $("#remComp").click(function() {
        disableAll();

        var currentCompany = detectViewer();
        var toRem = $("#viewer" + currentCompany);

        if(parseInt(currentCompany) !== 1){
            toRem.remove();

            viewHolder.animate({marginTop: '+=' + moveVertAmount + 'px'}, 'slow', function(){
                enableAll();
            });

        } else if(parseInt(currentCompany) == 1) {
            alert("You can't remove your only company!");
            enableAll();
        } else {
            enableAll();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues which makes me think it may be elsewhere.  Can you post the snippet that declares opiHolder?  That's the only thing that looks relatively different or missing between the two code snippets to me.

Comment: var opiHolder = $(".opiHolder");

Which is just a div.

Comment: maybe is working ... put an alert in the enableAll function to see if it gets there.

Comment: It doesn't get there, that's why I'm here.  Also, there is a script error, but I can't debug it with ie.  I downloaded a javascript debugger for it, but the error doesn't come up.

Comment: you have to put more complete code here // or a link to an online example

Answer (score 1):

1. check your MIME type for the script tag. should be type="text/javascript"
2. i don't see the code calling for the function slideRight().

Comment: I reduced the problem down to the point where it is clear to me now that IE isn't following the callback on the animation.

I have to ship this product so I just got rid of the damn animation.

Answer (score 0):

Check you're effectively calling slideRight().
Check the values of **leftMarg** and **fullWidth**, it's possible that the expression "fullWidth + leftMarg > opiWidth" isn't true, so you never will see the alert().

Regards

Comment: It works perfectly in FF and Chrome, and other functions even work in ie, it's JUST the function call in the callback that isn't triggering.